# Issues with text copying in the Syncfusion Document Editor

Tags: angular, editor, document, syncfusion

I am encountering issues with text copying in the Syncfusion Document Editor for Angular. In the attached document, when I attempt to copy the second sentence and paste it elsewhere, some text are missing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F50dk.png)

Expecting paste normally

Answer (score 1):

We were unable to reproduce the reported issue in our latest version v24.2.9 with the created document. We have attached a sample for your reference. Please cross-check that, and If the issue persists after using this suggested solution, we recommend you to create a ticket with Syncfusion support and please share the document you have used on your end and exact replication video in the ticket for the further investigation.

**To create a support ticket:** https://support.syncfusion.com/support/tickets/create

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nabd67-vyzzwq?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fdata.ts